# How to make Activity Function to accept json input when developing Azure Durable Function (Python)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have Azure Durable Function. It is mostly based on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

I'm trying to migrate reqular HTTP Trigger as Durable Function?

I have modified code to accept json in HTTP Start and Orchestrator Functions.
However Activity Function cannot take in json.
How to modify HelloActivity to accept json? Following line seems to cause issue.

```
def main(datajson: str) -> str:
```

**HelloOrchestrator:**

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

    # Take the json data from the DurableOrchestrationContext, which was passed during the invocation
    data = context._input
    data = json.loads(data)
    logging.info(f"Orchestrator: Input is: {data}")
    
    result1 = yield context.call_activity('HelloActivity', data)
    #result1 = yield context.call_activity('HelloActivity', "ThisWouldWork")

    return [result1]
    main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

**HelloActivity**

```
import logging

def main(datajson: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Activity datajson :" + datajson)
    return f"Hello world"
```

**Error:**

```
Function 'HelloOrchestrator (Orchestrator)' failed with an error. Reason: Message: 
Activity function 'HelloActivity' failed:  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not 
"dict") to str 
 {"$type":"System.Exception, 
System.Private.CoreLib","ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":" TypeError: can only 
concatenate str (not \"dict\") to str","Data":null,"InnerException":{"$type":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException,
```

Comment: Your error is with this line **logging.info(f"Orchestrator: Input is: {data}")**. Pass the original string (context._input) and not the **dictionary** object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @[John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) , For your suggestion Posting it as an answer to help other community .

> ````
> Reason: Message:  Activity function 'HelloActivity' failed: 
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not  "dict") to str  ```
> ````

For the above error :

" Your error is with this line **`logging. info(f"Orchestrator: Input is: {data}")`**,
Pass the original string `(context._input)` and not the **dictionary** object ."

For more information please refer this [Blog](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) .